# proving $ \mathbb{Z}/12 \not\cong \mathbb{Z}/6 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2$ as $\mathbb{Z}/12$ modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module

I know this is false for $\mathbb{Z}$ modules, by the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups. I don't know if this still holds true when they are taken as modules over $\mathbb{Z}/12$.

Comment: suppose $\phi$ is an isomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}/12$-modules from one module to the other. can you show that $\phi$ is also an $\mathbb{Z}$-module homomorphism? what can you conclude?

Comment: in general, we have the following: let $R$ be a (commutative, unital) ring and $I<R$ an ideal. if $M$ and $N$ are left $R$-modules and $I$ annihilates $M$ and $N$, then there is a unique way to make $M$ and $N$ into $R/I$-modules in a way that is compatible with the $R$-module structure. can you show that a function $M\to N$ is then a homomorphism of $R$-modules if and only it is a homomorphism of $R/I$-modules?

Comment: An isomorphism of $R$-modules $M$ and $N$ is in particular a group isomorphism between $M$ and $N$ (forgetting about the $R$-scaling on both of them).  That is, isomorphic $R$-modules at least have to be isomorphic groups under addition.  Therefore two nonisomorphic abelian groups can't be the underlying additive groups of isomorphic modules (over any commutative ring).

Comment: Something else to consider is that there is *no extra information* when you refer to the groups as $\mathbf Z/12$-modules: an abelian group is automatically a $\mathbf Z$-module is only one possible way: multiplication by 1 is the identity, so multiplication by $2 = 1+1$ has to be ordinary doubling, and so on. Since the groups involved have all elements killed by 12, the only possible $\mathbf Z/12$-module structure you can have here is the additive structure with repeated addition as multiplication. Calling these "$\mathbf Z/12$-modules" is no information at all beyond the group structure.